# geom_bar: custom spacing between bars in

Tags: r, geom-bar

I have a data set containing survey responses from many different regions in different countries. Using a bar chart, I want to show the number of respondents from each region, and visually group them together by country. I though I'd do that by manually adjusting the space between the bars in the chart. In other words, set a small space between regions of the same country, and then a jump before the next region from another country. Hope this makes sense.

When I google this, width and position_dodge come up a lot, but they don't seem suited for getting different spaces between different bars. Is there any way to do this without restructuring the data set?

Comment: Hi Norasy. It is very difficult for us to know whether you need to restructure your data because we don't have your data. A short description of your data set is not adequate to be able to replicate your problem. Could you please either share your data set using `dput`, or create a little dummy data set that replicates your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help you without your data, but maybe this is a good solution for you, providing a little space, but also conveying the information in a neat way:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'), 
                 member = c('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'), 
                 value = c(10, 15, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 40, 30))

ggplot(data = df,
       aes(member, value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~group, shrink = T, drop = T, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

You can also manipulate the size of the space between the plots if you want using something like:

`+ theme(panel.spacing = unit(50, "pt"))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, just what I needed! I have one last question, if you have time for that too. One of the regions have no observations, but I would still like it to be included in the chart. Say for example that there is a region B3, but with no observations. How do I represent this visually in the chart?

Comment: Glad the answer works for you, please mark it as accepted so future users with the same question are helped as well. As for regions with no observations: Make sure to include them in your dataset with a value of 0 or NA. This way they will be on the x-axis but with an 'empty' bar.

Comment: Will do. I should have mentioned that in my data set, I don't have the column "value". I have only specified the x in ggplot(aes()), and so the y variable (count) is generated when using ggplot. I am therefore not sure how to "include" B3 in the data set. Since B3 is never observed it will not be counted either.

Comment: Ah. In that case I think you will need to restructure your data set slightly by creating a value (or count) column and merging it with all regions. `dplyr` is a useful package to accomplish that.